# Can't sign into profile to save in GTA 5

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I am signed in into a profile, but when I try saving my GTA 5 says I need to sign in to a profile in order to save.

I chose another profile, but it still showed the same thing. Please help?!

Answer (score 1):

I was given the similar advice and it worked.However, it was suggested I do the following first:

- clear out my consoles content cache.
- delete 1.22 and heist updates from my consoles HDD and re-download.
- then do the sign Out thing

Jonathan suggests:

> Hey there Broken,
>
> I suggest that you try the following:
>
> - Delete your profile (profile only, not profile and all items).    * Make sure to restart your console. Typically with anyone having
>     instant log out issues when starting a game/app, that process will
>     resolve the issue.
> - Clear the system cache.
> - Re-download your profile

Comment: I formated the answer to best of my ability. I assume the later half is copied from a seperate answer somewhere. Feel free to revert or improve my edits, if need be.

Answer (score -2):

Try to change your xbox time to the right time